# ASP.Net Live streaming IP camera video and audio

Tags: c#, asp.net, camera, streaming

Hi all dear developers.

I need show **live video and audio streaming in a web page developed by asp.net** language.
Could anybody help me on this situation:
I want to know if there is an efficient and general and easy way.
I searched for hours about it: one solution is use "Wawza media server" which is too expensive for our project. (By wawza we can change RTSP to RTMP and then give it to jw player.)
I want a free way!
Please help me on this.

thanks for your attention

Comment: Have you tried one of the services like Ustream.com or justin.tv and embedding it in your site?

Comment: Did you get any optimized solution? please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this change up to your stream! is it RTP? RTSP? wowza is the best at right now, what about Adobe's solutions? or you have to create your own which is harder one.
a) [Adobe's Streaming Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/)
b) [Adobe's RTMP Protocol](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html)
c) [Adobe's Flash Player](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/)
d) [F4v/Flv video format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html)

These above software's are designed specifically for web applications to provide end user seamless, secured, uninterrupted, high quality video.

If you want some hands on then you can try [Red5](http://red5.org/) (Open Source Flash Server written in Java) or [rtpmd](http://www.rtmpd.com/) (C++ RTPM server)

Comment: my stream is RTSP. but wowza is too expensive for me I want another cheap solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use IIS Media Services (http://www.iis.net/media) and Smooth Streaming Client (http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothClient) to stream live video.

Comment: iis media services can't read from RTSP protocol supported by cameras and need to change it